# Woocommerce rest api not working with basic auth but with query string

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Hello guys i have a question with my Woocommerce rest Api working in dev environement but not in prod environement. I double checked ConsomerKey/secret. Working on postMan with query_string but not with basic auth.

trying to call https://website/wp-json/wc/v2/orders/677847/notes
and getting a

> {
>       "code": "rest_cannot_access",
>       "message": "Only authenticated users can access this endpoint.",
>       "data": {
>           "status": 401
>       } }

but if i do https://www.twebsite.com/wp-json/wc/v2/orders/677847/notes?consumer_key=CK&consumer_secret=CS it's working.

Any idea?

Comment: that can come from the hoster which blocks the authorisation headers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with "OAuth1.0" which also need consumer Key and Secret key. If you didn't try with this make a trial.